# Brute Force String Matching Concept

Tags: string, algorithm, search, time-complexity, brute-force

I saw this question in one of the book. It states as follows:

```
         Suppose we use brute-force string matching to search for a pattern of length     
         m in a string of length n. In which of these cases will the worst-case
         running time be MAXIMUM? (k>1 is 
         an integer constant.)

         A. m = n-k
         B. m = n/k
         C. m = (n)^(1/k)
         D. m = k
```

For me it just doesn't make any sense how will be sure the pattern we get from any of the 4 option
will give us the worst-case time complexity.
Since k is a constant so for different values of n and k we will be getting different length of m.
How does it affect the complexity of the searching algorithm ?

PS: What I will choose is the 4th option considering that n is very large and k = 1.

But again for that case also I have to make assumptions and moreover that is a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your brute force string search, the number of tests you have to perform is:

```
m(n-m)
```

That is, you need to test for m in each position it could start from (n-m), and each test for m takes m characters.

This function is at its maximum when the gradient is zero, so, differentiating with respect to `m`, you get:

```
n-2m=0
```

This is option B.

Answer (score 0):

Worst running time of brute-force `R(m,n) = (n - m + 1) * m`. (which is O(mn), but lets keep precise value for the moment).

You need to choose such `m`, that `R(m,n)` above becomes maximum, that will be your answer.

- A. `m = n - k; R = (k + 1) * (n - k)` - i.e. n multiplied by a constant, i.e. O(n) - not too bad
  ......
- D. `m = k; R = (n - k + 1) * k` - same O(n).

So the answer must be one of B, C. Can you figure out which one based on the described idea ? (hint: option B will give you quadratic O(n^2) complexity)